# python to download xml and not print anything in the command line

Tags: python, xml, wget

I currently use this in my python script:

```
os.system("sudo wget -P /etc/lirc/http://localhost:80/example.xml")`
```

which prints this in command line when i run the script:

```
--2015-04-17 13:26:27--  http://localhost:80/example.xml
Connecting to http://localhost:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/xml]
Saving to: /etc/lirc/example'

[ <=>                                   ] 612         --.-K/s   in 0s
```

what else can i use to not have this print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the `--quiet` flag to wget and see if that gets rid of it all for you